# PHP Excel Reader : Code error last row repeated many no of times

Tags: php, excel

This is my `mydata.xls` Excel sheet image:

[image: mydata.xls Excel sheet]

my php code:

```
<?php
// include class file
include("Excel/reader.php");

// initialize reader object
$excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

// read spreadsheet data...
$excel->read('mydata.xls');    

// iterate over Excel sheet cells and save to database table//////////
$x=2;
while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {

  $y=1;
  while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
 //save data to an array..
 $z=$y-1;
 $data[$z]=$excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y];

    $y++;
  } //end 2 while 

  //store array values to variables..
  $st_id=$data[0];
  $marks=$data[1];
  $co_type=$data[2];
  $status=$data[3];

  echo $st_id."</br>";

  $x++;
}//end 1 while

?>
```

Output Image:

[image: code output image]

problem: how to stop showing last row repeated.....????????????? last row value print many no of times how to stop that?? plzz tell the code error & how to fix this problem????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pulling data out of a 2-dimensional spreadsheet, then assign that data to a 1-dimensional array:

```
 $data[$z]=$excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y];
       ^^--- 1D array
```

You then always echo the SAME cells:

```
  $st_id=$data[0];
               ^---hard coded
```

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here at all.

Comment: I want to print those student numbers????????actually I'm try to insert those data to an database table....

Comment: Actually I'm trying to insert those data to my database table..before do that I tried to print one of this variable & see the result...If result is prints correct then I can insert those data to the table...

Comment: can anyone plzz tell me how to insert above excel sheet data to mysql database by using phpexcel?????

Comment: actuallly i want know : Import Excel (XLS) document into MySQL database